# didUpdateLocations delegate of CLLocationManager is not called in iOS 11 and Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

Hi have to fetch device current location and for this I am using CLLocationManager class but didUpdateLocations is not calling.

I am

My code and plist are below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `locationManger?.delegate = self` is set in `viewDidLoad` ?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore yes, but when I set delegate in viewWillAppear then still not working.

Comment: Did you request for location from the user?
 `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` or `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`

Comment: Try implementing the didFailWithError method to ensure it's not failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Requires GPS to track persons</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Requires GPS to track persons</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Requires GPS to track persons</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
    </array>
```

add this in viewdidLoad

```
locationManager.delegate = self
   self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
   self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Comment: I used this code. But still not working.

Comment: @ajeetsharma once delete the app & run again

Comment: thanks!! its working :D (y)